# XML UTF-8 data being written differently

Tags: xml, utf-8

Unfortunately I'm working in an obscure platform called uniPaaS so I'm probably after some platform-agnostic advice.

I've got a Web Service request where the XML document contains those irritating smart quotes. The byte data for the character is `E2 80 99` (which is a [`00002019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`](http://www.tachyonsoft.com/uc0020.htm))

[image: Wireshark capture of SOAP request]

When I write the XML file to disk on our staging server, it writes it correctly. When I write it on our production server, it totally changes the values of those bytes and malforms the XML document:

[image: Hex comparison of the two files]

`E2 80 99` becomes `92`. Has anyone ever seen this sort of behaviour before? It seems to only be that one byte string (but the SOAP resonse is 50Mb large, so I haven't had a chance to diff the entire file).

Comment: Far too little information. Please briefly describe your platform. Also: How is the file written to disk? What differences are there between staging & production? What program exactly does the writing? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @sleske, I can't really provide that information as the environment (uniPaaS) is a RAD P/SaaS tool, so all that information is abstracted away. The two systems are identical (cloned versions of eachother), but Ignacio was able to spot the pattern between the two files, which helps a lot.

Comment: In case you didn't already figure it out from Ignacio's answer, `E2 80 99` isn't becoming `92 73 20`, it's becoming just `92`. The `73` and `20` are the following characters.

Comment: @Laurence - yeah I did see that after his answer. I hadn't noticed it on my own, but after seeing his code I did (That also explains the 3kb discrepancy in file size over approx 50,000 records).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's encoding it as CP1251.

```
>>> '\x92'.decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x80\x99'
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I know what the problem is now, and it's not something I can fix, I'll have to open a bug report with the platform developers.

Comment: Nice job. While we are busy guessing: Maybe the problem is that somewhere some encoder defaults to the standard OS encoding (Java e.g. likes to do this). If the standard OS encoding is set differently on the two systems, that might cause the problem.